# Unable to retrieve data from API using Express NodeJS and MongoDB, loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm attempting to create a Rest API using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB. I am currently running on my local host :3000. When I try to restart and run the server I am using the route `http://localhost:3000/drinks`

I use Postman to send HTTP requests.
  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

While trying to send the route above, it does not retrieve any information. It just continues load.

This is my first time creating a REST API and I'm not sure why it isn't retrieving the data. Attached below is my code. Thanks in advance!

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    drink = require('./routes/drinks');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
    });

app.get('/drinks', drink.findAll);
app.get('/drinks/:id', drink.findById);                                                                       

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

drinks.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('drinkdb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Connected to 'drinkdb' database");
            db.collection('drinks', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("The 'drinks' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
                        populateDB();
                    }
                });
        }
    });

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving drink: ' + id);
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
            collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
                    res.send(item);
                });
        });
};

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, drinks) {
                    res.send(drinks);
                });
        });
};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Populate database with sample data -- Only used once: the first time the application is started.                   
// You'd typically not find this code in a real-life app, since the database would already exist.                     
var populateDB = function() {

    var drinks = [
    {
            id: "1",
            name: "Margarita",
            ingredients: ["Tequila","Lime juice","Triple Sec","Lime","Salt","Ice"],
            measurements: ["2 oz","1 oz","1 oz","1","optional","optional"],
            directions: "Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass. Served: On the roc\
ks; poured over ice. Optional: Salt the rim of the glass by rubbing lime on it so it sticks."
    },
   {
            id: "2",
            name: "Strawberry Margarita",
            ingredients: ["Tequila", "Lime juice","Triple Sec","Strawberries","Lime","Salt", "Ice"],
            measurements: ["2 oz","1 oz", "1 oz", "3 1/2 cups", "1", "optional", "optional"],
            directions: "Combine strawberries, ice, tequila, lime juice, and triple sec in a blender, and process unt\
il the mixture is smooth. Carefully pour into the glass. Served: On the rocks; poured over ice. Optional: Salt the ri\
m of the glass by rubbing lime on it so it sticks."
   }];

    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
            collection.insert(drinks, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
        });
};
```

Warnings are:

```
express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement server.js:6:5
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
```

Comment: add some console.log() statements to your code to find out how far it is getting.  As a starting point - in your findAll function and possibly even in the call-back for your app.get('/drinks',..)

Comment: Are you sure that your db is started ? If yes, is it binded to 27017 ?

Comment: Ok I did that and it is having problems with line collection.find().toArray(function(err, drinks) {res.send(drinks);}); @Tim

Comment: check if an error is being returned:
if (err){ console.error('err:',err);}

Comment: I added that line of code and no error was returned @Tim

Comment: I'd recommend:
1. updating your code (in this post to stackoverflow) with your updates.
2. logging the result from drinks (in your db query)
3. use the end function to send back just a string - exp: res.end('test'); to see if postman gets that

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing warnings now: express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement server.js:6:5
 connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15 @Tim

Comment: app.configure is depreciated (Express 4.x onwards) - see https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Answer (score 1):

I think Ashley is on the right track.  But to make it more clear where the problem is happening try using this as a guide:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
app.get('/drinks', function (req, res) {
  drink.findAll(req, res);
});
```

Then you can add logging in between this call and in your findAll function.

Comment: Thanks Tim, thought my method would word but perhaps not. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your models (drinks.js) accept two parameters (req & res) but on your route you don't pass in any parameters.

Try the following:

```
app.get('/drinks', function(req, res) {
    drink.findAll(req, res);
});

app.get('/drinks/:id', function(req, res){
    drink.findById(req, res);
});
```

Alternatively, you could achieve the same with a callback based structure:

server.js

...

```
app.get('/drinks', function(req, res) {
    drink.findAll(function(err, drinks){
        res.send(drinks)
    });
});
```

...

drinks.js

...

```
exports.findAll = function(callback) {
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, drinks) {
                    callback(err, drinks)
                });
        });
};
```

(error handling required)
...

Comment: I add those lines and ReferenceError: req is not defined